# Cumulative amount by Date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, klipfolio

We have a table holding the values of a cumulative amount by date, for instance:

```
|       date.      |          |

| 2015-03-01 | 1.23 |

| 2015-03-04 | 1.98 |

| 2015-03-06 | 2.23 |

And we have a table with all dates we need, for instance:

|       date.      |

| 2015-03-01 |

| 2015-03-02 |

| 2015-03-03 |

| 2015-03-04 |

| 2015-03-05 |

| 2015-03-06 |

We would like to get:

|       date.      |          |

| 2015-03-01 | 1.23 |

| 2015-03-02 | 1.23 |

| 2015-03-03 | 1.23 |

| 2015-03-04 | 1.98 |

| 2015-03-05 | 1.98 |

| 2015-03-06 | 2.23 |
```

Is that possible just using SQL itself?

I'm having a bad time trying to figure how to do that.

I have tried some cross joins operations, without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized - it should be even simplier (much simplier) in this particular case.
Try below

```
SELECT 
  dates_table.date,
  MAX(amounts.amount) OVER(ORDER BY dates_table.date) AS amount
FROM dates_table LEFT JOIN amounts_table
ON dates_table.date  = amounts_table.date
```

> As some of you have problem adopting this answer and thinking it
>   doesnt work  - I just added below example to "prove" above is working
>   :o)

```
SELECT    
  dates.date,   
  MAX(amounts.amount) OVER(ORDER BY dates.date) AS amount 
FROM (   
  SELECT * FROM      
    (SELECT '2015-03-01' AS [date]),     
    (SELECT '2015-03-02' AS [date]),     
    (SELECT '2015-03-03' AS [date]),     
    (SELECT '2015-03-04' AS [date]),     
    (SELECT '2015-03-05' AS [date]),     
    (SELECT '2015-03-06' AS [date])   
) AS dates 
LEFT JOIN (  
  SELECT * FROM     
    (SELECT '2015-03-01' AS [date],  1.23 AS amount),     
    (SELECT '2015-03-04' AS [date], 1.98 AS amount),      
    (SELECT '2015-03-06' AS [date], 2.23 AS amount) 
) AS amounts 
ON dates.date  = amounts.date
```

Result is:

```
Row dates_date  amount   
1   2015-03-01  1.23     
2   2015-03-02  1.23     
3   2015-03-03  1.23     
4   2015-03-04  1.98     
5   2015-03-05  1.98     
6   2015-03-06  2.23
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not being able to reproduce this one, it's not getting the values correctly after the second amount change, the first one worked amazingly, thank you very much

Comment: sure, no problem - it worked on my quick test  - so I wanted to share it too.  I do believe - It still should work - but you need to be careful with fields naming - in case if you will have chance to try to make it work :o)

Comment: Added example to the answer

Comment: Mikhail, sorry, I couldn't make it work before, but I got you now. Its an awesome solution. Thanks again

Comment: no problem. glad you were able to make it work for yourself

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
  [date],
  amount
FROM (
  SELECT
    [date],
    amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY delta) AS win
  FROM (  
    SELECT 
      dates_table.date AS [date],
      DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(dates_table.date), TIMESTAMP(amounts_table.date)) AS delta,
      amount
    FROM amounts_table CROSS JOIN dates_table
    WHERE DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(dates_table.date), TIMESTAMP(amounts_table.date)) >= 0
  )
)
WHERE win = 1
ORDER BY 1
```